# How to fix full screen overlay from creating scroll bars on main div

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a full-screen overlay that's active once a button is clicked. When the overlay goes away after clicking, scroll bars appear and then immediately disappear creating a quick shift in the app.

I'm using react-copy-to-clipboard and styled-components.

I figured since `<CopyToClipboard />` is the parent div, I would style that, but it threw everything off and doing so isn't straight forward since it's a pre-made component from react-copy-to-clipboard.

Here's my component code:

```
return (
      <CopyToClipboard text={background} onCopy={this.changeCopyState}>
        <MainColorBox style={{ background }}>
          <CopyOverlay show={copied} style={{ background }} />
          <CopyMessage show={copied}>
            <h1>Copied!</h1>
            <p text={isLightColor}>{background}</p>
          </CopyMessage>
          <div className='copy-container'>
            <BoxContent>
              <span text={isDarkColor}>{name}</span>
            </BoxContent>
            <CopyBtn text={isLightColor}>Copy</CopyBtn>
          </div>
          {showLink && (
            <Link to={moreUrl} onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>
              <SeeMoreBtn text={isLightColor}>MORE</SeeMoreBtn>
            </Link>
          )}
        </MainColorBox>
      </CopyToClipboard>
    );
```

Here are my styles for `<MainColorBox />` and `<CopyOverlay />`

```
export const MainColorBox = styled.div`
  width: 20%;
  height: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -3.5px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

  &:hover ${CopyBtn} {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s;
  }

  ${({ theme }) => theme.lg`
    width: 25%;
    height: 20%
  `}

  ${({ theme }) => theme.md`
    width: 50%;
    height: 10%
  `}

  ${({ theme }) => theme.xs`
    width: 100%;
    height: 5%;
  `}
`

export const CopyOverlay = styled.div`
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(0.1);

  ${({ show }) => show && css`
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 10;
    transform: scale(50);
    position: fixed;
  `}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
position:fixed;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Should fix this issue

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, but nothing changed. The issue is still present.